# settings_fields() doesn't work for other roles except admin

Tags: plugin-development

In my custom plugin, I want other user roles can also save the plugin settings. And I use settings_fields('custom_options') function to save settings.

When I am logged in as an editor or any other role, on clicking the button I am redirected to the while screen page with a message Sorry, you are not allowed to manage these options.

Please, can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the capability required to save settings you can use the [`option_page_capability_{$option_page}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/option_page_capability_option_page/) filter, where `{$option_page}` is the value passed to `settings_field()` on your settings page.

So if you have this on your settings page:

```
<?php settings_fields( 'wpse_294802_options' ); ?>
```

You can change the required capability to save with the `option_page_capability_wpse_294802_options` filter:

```
function wpse_294802_option_page_capability() {
    return 'edit_pages';
}
add_filter( 'option_page_capability_wpse_294802_options', 'wpse_294802_option_page_capability' );
```

Now users with the `edit_pages` capability can save your settings. Just make sure that you set a matching capability when adding the settings page or the user will be able to save your settings page, but not *see* it.

PS: `submit_button()` isn't really relevant here, it's just a function that outputs an `<input>` element with the proper classes and text. It doesn't play a role in determining how or if settings are saved. The important part for that is `settings_fields()`.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help. It resolved my problem. Yes, thanks for directing me towards the correct path :)

Comment: I have one more query, the above solution works only for editor role. If I try any other role example: author it gives me the error message. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Well look at the answer. The code gives access to anyone who has the edit_pages capability. If you want different roles to have access use a different capability. Read about capabilities here https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities